4n-dimensional lattices and Gauss congruence
I'm interested in integer sequences $(a_n)$ satisfying the Gauss congruence, i.e. sequences of the form
$$a_n=\sum_{d\mid n}b_d d$$
for some other integer sequence $(b_n)$.
It appears that the theta-series for $4n$-dimensional lattices often satisfy this congruence. For example, if $a_n$ is the number of points in $\mathbb{Z}^4$ that are distance $n$ from the origin, then $a_n$ satisfies the above recurrence with $b_d=8$ when $d\nmid 4$, and $b_d=0$ otherwise.
Can anybody give an explanation of this phenomenon, or places I should look next?
Thanks!
